# Как распарсить XML файл с одинаковыми тегами?

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть XML файл, теги которого одинаковы.

```
<regions_list>
<region type="continent" name="europe"
    translate="=Europe" inner_download_suffix="europe" boundary="no" poly_extract="europe">

<!-- north-europe -->
        <region name="denmark" lang="da" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="estonia" lang="et" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="iceland" lang="is" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="faroe-islands" translate="Faroe Islands;entity=node" lang="fo" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="finland" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="fi,sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
            <region map="no" name="aland" translate="name:fi=Ahvenanmaa;admin_level=3;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="eastern-finland" translate="Eastern Finland;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="northern-finland" map="no" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northern Finland;entity=relation" boundary="no">
                <region type="srtm" name="lapland" translate="Lapland;entity=relation"/>
                <region type="srtm" name="northern-ostrobothnia" translate="name:en=Northern Ostrobothnia;entity=relation"/>
            </region>
            <region type="srtm" name="southern-finland" translate="Southern Finland;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="western-finland" translate="Western Finland;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="latvia" lang="lv" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="lithuania" lang="lt" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="norway" srtm="no" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="nb,nn" poly_extract="north-europe" join_map_files="yes">
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="akershus"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="astfold" translate="Østfold;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="aust-agder"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="buskerud"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="finnmark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hedmark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hordaland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="more-og-romsdal" translate="Møre og Romsdal;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nordland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nord-trondelag" translate="Nord-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oppland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oslo"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="rogaland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sogn-og-fjordane" translate="Sogn og Fjordane;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sor-trondelag" translate="Sør-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="telemark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="troms"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vest-agder"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vestfold"/>
            <region name="svalbard-and-jan-mayen" translate="Svalbard;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="sweden" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="blekinge" translate="Blekinge län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="dalarna" translate="Dalecarlia;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gavleborg" translate="Gävleborgs län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gotland" translate="Gotlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="halland" translate="Hallands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jamtland" translate="Jämtlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jonkoping" translate="Jönköpings län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kalmar" translate="Kalmar län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kronoberg" translate="Kronobergs län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="norrbotten" translate="Norrbottens län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="orebro" translate="Örebro län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="ostergotland" translate="Östergötlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="skane" translate="Skåne län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sodermanland" translate="Södermanlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="stockholm" translate="Stockholms län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="uppsala" translate="Uppsala län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="varmland" translate="Värmlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasterbotten" translate="Västerbottens län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasternorrland" translate="Västernorrlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastmanland" translate="Västmanlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastra-gotaland" translate="Västra Götalands län;entity=relation"/>
        </region>

<!-- east-europe -->
        <region name="belarus" lang="be,ru" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="bulgaria" lang="bg" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="czech-republic" inner_download_prefix="$name" translate="Czech Republic;entity=node" lang="cs,sk" poly_extract="east-europe" join_map_files="yes">
            <region name="jihovychod" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Southeast;ref=CZ06;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="jihozapad" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Southwest;ref=CZ03;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="moravskoslezsko" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Moravia-Silesia;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="praha" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Prague;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="severovychod" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northeast;ref=CZ05;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="severozapad" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northwest;ref=CZ04;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="stredni-cechy" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Central Bohemia;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="stredni-morava" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Central Moravia;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="hungary" lang="hu" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="moldova" lang="ro" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="poland" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="pl" poly_extract="east-europe" join_map_files="yes">
            <region name="greater-poland" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Greater Poland;entity=node"/>
            <region name="kuyavian-pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Kuyavian-Pomerania;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lesser-poland" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Lesser Poland;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lodz" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Łódź;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lower-silesian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Lower Silesia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lublin" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Lublin Voivodeship;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="lubusz" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no"/>
            <region name="masovian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Masovia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="opole" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Opole Voivodeship;entity=node"/>
            <region name="podlachian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Podlachia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Pomerania;entity=node"/>
            <region name="silesian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Silesia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="subcarpathian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Subcarpathia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="swietokrzyskie" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Holy Cross;entity=node"/>
            <region name="warmian-masurian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Warmian-Masurian Voivodeship;entity=node"/>
            <region name="west-pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="West Pomerania;entity=node"/>
        </region>
```

Мне необходимо достать все страны из Европы `<region type="continent" name="europe"...` все страны, которые являются ChildNodes (Например, `<region name="denmark" lang="da" poly_extract="north-europe"/>`).

Я парщу с помощью XmlPullParser.

```
public static Region parsedXMLForEurope(String xmlFile) {
    List<Region> allRegions = new ArrayList<>();
    Region region = new Region("Europe");

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(new StringReader(xmlFile));
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i("XMLParser", "******************");
            Log.i("XMLParser", "Current counrtry is: " + parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(parser.getName().equals("region") && parser.getAttributeValue(null, "poly_extract").contains("europe")) {
                        Log.i("XMLParser", "******************");
                        Log.i("XMLParser", "Current country is: " + parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        region.pushRegion(new Region(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name")));
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    Log.i("XMLParser", "******************");
                    Log.i("XMLParser", "Current country is: " + parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                    break;

            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return region;
}
```

Я получаю только первые 5 стран, но когда у нода есть дети

```
<region name="finland" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="fi,sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
            <region map="no" name="aland" translate="name:fi=Ahvenanmaa;admin_level=3;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="eastern-finland" translate="Eastern Finland;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="northern-finland" map="no" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northern Finland;entity=relation" boundary="no">
```

цикл полностью прекращается.

[image: Log Messages]

Comment: Принципиально XmlPullParser парсить?

Comment: Нет, не принципиально. Главное результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private String rootRegionName;
    private int depth = -1; // По умолчанию собирать всех потомков

    private List<String> regions;

    private boolean inWantedBranch = false;
    private int currentLevel = 0;
    private int branchLevel;

    public SAXHandler(String regionName) {
        this.rootRegionName = regionName;
        regions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public SAXHandler(String regionName, int depth) {
        this(regionName);
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if(qName.equals("region")) {
            String name = attributes.getValue("name");

            if((name != null) && (name.equals(rootRegionName))) {
                inWantedBranch = true;
                branchLevel = currentLevel;
            }

            if(inWantedBranch) {
                if(depth == -1) {
                    regions.add(name);
                }
                else if(currentLevel <= (branchLevel + depth)) {
                    regions.add(name);
                }
            }
        }
        ++currentLevel;
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        --currentLevel;
        if(qName.equals("region") && (currentLevel == branchLevel)) {
            inWantedBranch = false;
        }
    }

    public List<String> getResult() {
        return regions;
    }
}


try {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    // Собираем непосредственных потомков региона "europe"
    SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler("europe", 1);
    saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile)), handler);

    List<String> countries = handler.getResult();
 }
 catch(SAXException ex) {}
 catch(ParserConfigurationException ex) {}
 catch(IOException ex) {}
```

Comment: Дай Вам Бог здоровья, добрый человек!